# node js callback - Will the order always be the same?

Tags: node.js, callback

I wrote the following function that takes a callback. I always thought that the content of a callback might be executed later. In this case it doesn't...

```
 doesSomething(function(){
        console.log("1");
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 10000)
        {
            console.log("hello");
            i = i + 1;
        }
    });
 console.log("2");
 console.log("3");
```

Whatever I do, "2" and "3" always comes after "1" and a thousand of "hello".
Like this:

**1

hello

hello

...

hello

hello

2

3**

What I thought it would do:
**2

3

1

hello

hello

...

hello

hello**

Even if this behaviour makes my life simpler I don't really understand why the execution is procedural.

Do you think that in some case it might go reverse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript is a single threaded language, but not the node.js runtime or the browser. There are certain functions provided by node.js or the browser that would trigger for a function to be assigned to a task queue to be processed in a separate thread

lets take your example and make dosomething async

this is your synchronous code that would print, 1 hello...,2,3

```
function doesSomething(callback) {
    callback();
}
doesSomething(function(){
    console.log("1");
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        console.log("hello");
        i = i + 1;
    }
});
console.log("2");
console.log("3");
```

and this is the async code, that prints out 3, 2, 1, hello ...

```
function doesSomething(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
}

doesSomething(function(){
    console.log("1");
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        console.log("hello");
        i = i + 1;
    }
});
console.log("2");
console.log("3");
```

to explain why the second code is async, you have to understand that `setTimeout` is not part of javascript, its an api provided by node.js and the browsers. setTimeout puts the callback function into a queue to be processed. At this time a separate thread runs the setTimeout and when the timer ends it puts the callback into a callback queue, and when the call stack is clear, whatever is in the callback queue will be moved to the call stack and processed.

in node you can use process.nextTick(yourFunction); to make it async, this is just another function that nodejs provides you which is better than using setTimeout (which I wont get into here) you can checkout https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick to understand more about process.nextTick

for more info check out this video [https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=19m25s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ%22what%20is%20the%20event%20loop%22)

Comment: Thanks ! I get it now. The video helped. To summarize, JS is single threaded but node isn't and provides functionnalities to create async code. This changes alot of things for me...

Answer (score 1):

From the output that you mention, I can say that there is nothing asynchronous happening in your code inside `doesSomething` and is probably looking like this:

```
   function doesSomething(callback) {
      <maybe some synchronous operations, e.g. no ajax or filesystem calls>

      callback();
  }
```

, so the order of the calling functions will be always the same, like you posted above:

1. doesSomething(callback)
2. console.log(2)
3. console.log(3)

If you want the order you mention you should call them like this:

1. console.log(2)
2. console.log(3)
3. doesSomething(callback)

This does not have to do something with node.js in particular. It is the way methods are executed in JavaScript, which is synchronous since it is single threaded.
When you call the method `doesSomething(callback)` it immediately executes it and nothing else until it completes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if my function does not have any synchronous call, what would ? What could I possibly add to my callback for the execution to go away till my function is finished ? (And that would reverse the order of the logs...)

Comment: It is the function `doesSomething` that you should alter, so it performs something asynchronous and then it calls the provided `callback`, e.g. something like a simple `setTimeout(callback, 1000)`

Answer (score 1):

It all depends upon how `doSomething()` calls its callback.  If it calls the callback synchronously (e.g. before it returns), then everything in that function will execute before `doSomething()` returns.  If it calls it asynchronously (sometime after it returns), then you will get a different order.

So, the order is determined by the code that you do not show us in `doSomething()`.

Based on the order you observe, `doSomething()` must be calling its callback synchronously and thus it will execute in order just like any other synchronous function call.

For example, here are two scenarios:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    callback();
}
```

This calls the callback passed to it synchronously and thus it will execute before `doSomething()` returns and thus it will execute before code that follows.

Whereas something like this;

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    fs.writeFile('foo.txt', callback);
}
```

or:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 50);
}
```

Will execute the callback asynchronously sometime later after the function has already returned and you will see a different execution order with your `console.log()` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I don't understand in your example is what makes writeFile and setTimeout some asynchrone functions in comparaison of mine. What in their stucture allows the execution NOT to wait for them ? Is it because of the nature of their work, like treating with files (for writeFile) ? Is it because they are also executing some callbacks ? I don't understand why calling them results in NOT waiting for them to finish...

Comment: Only functions implemented in native code or using native code functions can be async. It takes lower level system support to interface directly with the event queue to do that. Both the functions I used have native code implementations and their doc explains about their callback.